# jquery plugin flexslider. function seems not return value

Tags: jquery, slide

why this code doesnt return current slide value?

```
function sliding(){
  var nrs = 0;

  $('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "fade",
    manualControls: ".flex-control-nav li a",
    controlsContainer: ".flex-container",
    after: function(slider) {
      if (slider.currentSlide == 2){
        var nrs = slider.currentSlide;
        slider.pause();
      }
    }
  });

  return nrs;
}
```

it always return zero only.
can help anyone?

Comment: It looks like you are just starting the slider, which defaults to the first slide.

Comment: do you have any idea how can get work it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it should just be

```
nrs = slider.currentSlide;
```

not

```
var nrs = slider.currentSlide;
```

Answer (score 0):

You're changing `nrs` in the `after` callback, while your function returns as soon as your slider is initialized. You need to use callbacks for this.

Comment: I try on atart,before and end but there is no change

Comment: @AolShqip What are you doing with the returned value? You cannot return from inside a callback function, to the outer function.

Comment: I want to initialize another slide when  current slide is 2

Comment: Then just add your new slider init code inside this if? ` if (slider.currentSlide == 2)`?

Answer (score 0):

With animatingTo you should get the correct index.

```
slider.animatingTo;
```

So try

```
if (slider.animatingTo == 2){
    var nrs = slider.animatingTo;
    slider.pause();
}
```